# e17 enlightenment on precise

Tags: 12.04, desktop-environments, enlightenment

I have been trying to add enlightenment off and on for over a week now with no luck. I've added the ppa i find everywhere, yet no luck. every time I try to add i get this:

e17:

```
 Depends: libecore-evas-svn-03 but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: libecore-imf-svn-03 but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: libecore-input-svn-03 but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: libecore-x-svn-03 but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: libedbus-svn-03 but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: libedje-svn-03 but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: libeet1 but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: libembryo0 but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: libevas-svn-03 but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: libevas-svn-03-engine-software-x11
 Depends: libedje-bin but it is not going to be installed
```

what in the world am i doing wrong or why can't i find these files to get it to work?

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify which PPA you are using - the correct 12.04 PPA is in this Q&A: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16932/how-do-i-install-enlightenment-e17

Comment: ppa:hannes-janetzek/enlightenment-svn

Comment: ok - please paste.ubuntu.com the output of `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured this one out after some tinkering. the problem was the validation key. I had to manually add it from the site and everything downloaded fine.

Comment: > the problem was the validation key. I had to manually add it from the site and everything downloaded fine. And you did this... how?

Comment: I copied the key from the repo page and added it under software sources authentication for the repo. I had a lot of issues with this repo since adding it including broken package issues of and on. The key wasn't added when adding the repo for some reason.